# How to use WebConfiguratonManager?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am new at ASP.net and VB.net. I am learning from the book "Beginning ASP.Net 3.5 in VB 2008"

The book is using `Web.config` and when I call it with

```
Private Conn As String = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyConnectionString").ConnectionString
```

There is error saying:

> Name `WebConfigurationManager` is not declared.

Is `WebConfigurationManager` a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably forgot:

```
System.Web.Configuration;
```

in a library.